# removeFromParent() does not remove a node, but makes it invisible

Tags: xcode, swift, xcode6, sprite-kit, xcode6.3

I have a **restartButton** that must appear when two bodies collide and when it happens for the first time, all goes great - bodies collide--> restartButton appears--> I restart level by touching restartButton.
It was a **"good, right restart"** And here problem starts...

After level been restarted, if I touch at center of the screen(where restartButton must appear when is called) game crashes, saying following:

**"Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Attemped to add a SKNode which already has a parent:  name:'(null)' particleTexture: 'enemyPart.png' (100 x 100) position:{721.33929, 175.39999} accumulatedFrame:{{inf, inf}, {inf, inf}}'
** First throw call stack:
(0x2a0fa137 etc.)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException"**

but restartButton is invisible and it couldn't even be there because no bodies have collided.

If after that "good restart" some enemy collide with player, restartButton appears for a moment and player, enemy1, enemy2, enemy3 are fadingOut from scene.

I would appreciate if someone can help

Here is code where you can see all that stuff:

```
import SpriteKit
import UIKit



let player = SKEmitterNode(fileNamed: "playerPart.sks")
let enemy1 = SKEmitterNode(fileNamed: "ePart.sks")
let enemy2 = SKEmitterNode(fileNamed: "ePart.sks")
let enemy3 = SKEmitterNode(fileNamed: "ePart.sks")
let restartButton = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "restartButton")
let playerCat: UInt32 = 0x1 << 0
let enemyCat: UInt32 = 0x1 << 1


class Level2: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

        physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self


        initWorld()
        movements()

        player.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 50)
        player.position = CGPointMake(819.2 , 693.8)
        player.zPosition = 1
        player.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = playerCat
        player.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = enemyCat
        player.targetNode = self
        self.addChild(player)

        enemy1.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: CGSizeMake(102, 102))
        enemy1.position = CGPointMake(819.2, 175.4)
        enemy1.zPosition = 1
        enemy1.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
        enemy1.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
        enemy1.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
        enemy1.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = enemyCat
        enemy1.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = playerCat
        enemy1.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0x0
        enemy1.targetNode = self
        enemy1.particleBirthRate = 150
        enemy1.particleLifetime = 10
        enemy1.particleLifetimeRange = 20
        enemy1.particlePositionRange = CGVectorMake(50, 60)
        enemy1.emissionAngle = 0
        enemy1.emissionAngleRange = 0
        enemy1.particleSpeed = 0
        enemy1.particleSpeedRange = 0


        enemy2.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: CGSizeMake(102, 102))
        enemy2.position = CGPointMake(614.4, 386.6)
        enemy2.zPosition = 1
        enemy2.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
        enemy2.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
        enemy2.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
        enemy2.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = enemyCat
        enemy2.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = playerCat
        enemy2.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0x0
        enemy2.targetNode = self
        enemy2.particleBirthRate = 150
        enemy2.particleLifetime = 10
        enemy2.particleLifetimeRange = 20
        enemy2.particlePositionRange = CGVectorMake(50, 60)
        enemy2.emissionAngle = 0
        enemy2.emissionAngleRange = 0
        enemy2.particleSpeed = 0
        enemy2.particleSpeedRange = 0

        enemy3.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: CGSizeMake(102, 102))
        enemy3.position = CGPointMake(409.6, 181.8)
        enemy3.zPosition = 1
        enemy3.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
        enemy3.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
        enemy3.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
        enemy3.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = enemyCat
        enemy3.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = playerCat
        enemy3.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0x0
        enemy3.targetNode = self
        enemy3.particleBirthRate = 150
        enemy3.particleLifetime = 10
        enemy3.particleLifetimeRange = 20
        enemy3.particlePositionRange = CGVectorMake(50, 60)
        enemy3.emissionAngle = 0
        enemy3.emissionAngleRange = 0
        enemy3.particleSpeed = 0
        enemy3.particleSpeedRange = 0


    func initWorld() {

        self.addChild(enemy1)
        self.addChild(enemy2)
        self.addChild(enemy3)

    }


    func movements() {

        let move11 = SKAction.moveTo(CGPointMake(819.2, 386.6), duration: 1.5)
        let move12 = SKAction.moveTo(CGPointMake(614.4, 386.6), duration: 1.5)
        let move13 = SKAction.moveTo(CGPointMake(614.4, 175.4), duration: 1.5)
        let move14 = SKAction.moveTo(CGPointMake(819.2, 175.4), duration: 1.5)
        let enemy1m = SKAction.sequence([move11, move12, move13, move14])
        let enemy1move = SKAction.repeatActionForever(enemy1m)

        let move21 = SKAction.moveTo(CGPointMake(614.4, 591.4), duration: 1.5)
        let move22 = SKAction.moveTo(CGPointMake(409.6, 591.4), duration: 1.5)
        let move23 = SKAction.moveTo(CGPointMake(409.6, 386.6), duration: 1.5)
        let move24 = SKAction.moveTo(CGPointMake(614.4, 386.6), duration: 1.5)
        let enemy2m = SKAction.sequence([move21, move22, move23, move24])
        let enemy2move = SKAction.repeatActionForever(enemy2m)

        let move31 = SKAction.moveTo(CGPointMake(409.6, 386.6), duration: 1.5)
        let move32 = SKAction.moveTo(CGPointMake(204.8, 386.6), duration: 1.5)
        let move33 = SKAction.moveTo(CGPointMake(204.8, 181.8), duration: 1.5)
        let move34 = SKAction.moveTo(CGPointMake(409.6, 181.8), duration: 1.5)
        let enemy3m = SKAction.sequence([move31, move32, move33, move34])
        let enemy3move = SKAction.repeatActionForever(enemy3m)

        enemy1.runAction(enemy1move)
        enemy2.runAction(enemy2move)
        enemy3.runAction(enemy3move)
    }


    func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
        let collision:UInt32 = (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask | contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask)

        if collision == (playerCat | enemyCat) {
            self.removeAllActions()
            self.runAction(SKAction.waitForDuration(0.1), completion: {
                self.runAction(SKAction.waitForDuration(0.2), completion:
                    {self.removeAllActions()
                        self.removeChildrenInArray([enemy1, enemy2, enemy3, player])})

                restartButton.size = CGSizeMake(200, 200)
                restartButton.position = CGPointMake(512, 384)
                restartButton.zPosition = 1
                self.addChild(restartButton)
            })


        }
    }




    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {

        for touch: AnyObject in touches {
            let location = touch.locationInNode(self)

            if (restartButton .containsPoint(location)) {
                restartButton.runAction(fadeAway)
                restartButton.removeFromParent()
                println(1)
                self.runAction(SKAction.waitForDuration(1.5), completion: {
                let repeatLevel = SKTransition.fadeWithDuration(2)
                let level2 = Level2(fileNamed: "Level2")
                self.view?.presentScene(level2, transition:     repeatLevel)


                })
            }

        }
    }

    override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
        /* Called before each frame is rendered */
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your restartButton is having its size set for the first time when your playerCat and enemyCat first collide, which is fine.

Since the restartButton now has a size. You can check if your touch is within the bounds of the restartButton.

```
if (restartButton .containsPoint(location)) {
```

Like you have done so, but at no point do you check wether the restartButton is added to the scene. 
A quick fix could possibly be:

```
if (restartButton.parent != nil && restartButton .containsPoint(location)) {
```

If dont specifically need to check if it with the bounds of the node. You could directly check using this instead. Which will eliminate the need to check for a parent.

```
if (self.nodeAtPoint(location) == restartButton) {
```

Another thing i noticed, in your collision detection, you never check if it has already collided. So you might run the same code multiple times, where you just keep removing all actions and then adding a new one.

You could add a simple have variable to prevent redudancy

```
var detectionMade = false
```

and reset at

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self

    initWorld()
    movements()

    detectionMade = false
    ...
```

and set to true when first colliding and checking

```
if collision == (playerCat | enemyCat) && !detectionMade {
    detectionMade = true
    ...
```

Comment: After adding this line 
`if (restartButton.parent == nil && restartButton .containsPoint(location)) {`
restartButton appears after a collision, but when I press it, nothing happens

Comment: My apologies, looks like i was writing that a bit too fast. Of course it should be restartButton.parent != nil, since you want to make sure that it has been added to the scene. I edited my answer, and also added an alternative way of checking if the button is being clicked, where there is no need to check for the parent.

Answer (score 0):

@martinmeincke I've done it! By doing THIS:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {

        for touch: AnyObject in touches {
            let location = touch.locationInNode(self)

            if (restartButton .containsPoint(location) && restartButton.parent == nil) {
                restartButton.runAction(fadeAway)

                println(1)



                }
            }

        }


    override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        for touch: AnyObject in touches {
            let location = touch.locationInNode(self)

            if (restartButton .containsPoint(location)) {
                restartButton.removeFromParent()
                self.runAction(SKAction.waitForDuration(1.5), completion: {
                    let repeatLevel = SKTransition.fadeWithDuration(2)
                    let level2 = Level2(fileNamed: "Level2")
                    self.view?.presentScene(level2, transition: repeatLevel)
            })

        }
    }
    }
```